# C++ building nesting functions during runtime

Tags: c++

So I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to figure out a way to build a series of functions based on input received during runtime. The basic idea is that I plan to have a function to create an Ability, which can be constructed of several Actions, which can have  several Shapes, which can have several effects. The code I planned out (without properly splitting functions or actually writing code yet) would be structured something like this:

```
//Planned function:
/*
Ability()
{
  Action 1()
  {
    Type of action
    Shape 1 of Action 1()
    {   
      Type of shape
      Effect 1 of Shape 1 of Action 1()
      {
        Type of effect
      }
      Any more effects?
    }   
    Any more shapes?
  }
Any more actions?
}
/**/
```

But I'm not quite sure what I would do to actively build a nesting set of functions like this based off of user input, store it, and use it as something I can run later during runtime without having to rebuild it.

My apologies if I'm just missing something obvious, I haven't really gotten past object classes yet.

Comment: Have you tried using classes?

Comment: If you want to create code dynamically at run time, then maybe the easiest way would be to generate code for an easy-to-embed scripting language like [lua](https://www.lua.org), since you can't really generate C++ functions at run-time.

Comment: @Vivick I'm not quite sure how I would use classes for that. So far, they seem like structs that can contain functions as well as data, but I don't know how I would use them to create and store something complex like what I'm after.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I plan to write all the code before it's compiled, not have users write out code and try to run it. I feel like C++ should be able to dynamically arrange functions inside eachother, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: @AuroraChroma What you're trying to do resembles what [this fairly simple class diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G1hpKVHXNW3bS9FTAd6xnEfwn2v9Gfen/view?usp=sharing) proposes

Comment: @Vivick I see, that helps a bit because I can tell that that's what I'm trying to do, but I'm not quite sure in what way I would accomplish that. Would I create a separate class for each type of function, create a collection of functions in each class representing the types of each function, and within each class's function, link to the next type of class? If I did that, how would I store a particular setup of these to be run whenever I need to call it?

Comment: As you can see I created a class for each "type" of data you enunciated. I made it generic enough (no members, no member funcitons, etc..) so you could attach what you need to them. Let's say that each "entity" or class exposes a member function `process`. An `Ability` would go through each of its `Action` and call its member function `process` which in turn would call each of this `Action`'s `Shape`'s `process` etc... . You could keep an array or `std::vector` of `Ability` so you could use them later (you could also store `Action`s, `Shape`s, etc... if you want to)

Comment: The point is that `UserInputParser` would act as a factory for each other entity (and would therefore create an instance of the said class or any of its subclasses) that you could store freely. You may have the need to have other classes that inherit from `Ability`, `Action`, `Shape` or `Effect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I would do to actively build a nesting set of functions like this based off of user input, store it, and use it as something I can run later during runtime without having to rebuild it.

So basically, what you need is to save a set of operations to be called later on. In software engineering, this is called the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). In short, each operation (command, action, function...) is modeled as an object which contains all the necessary information to perform the action and a method that triggers  (executes, performs, runs...) it. Usually, these objects conform to the same interface so that you can trigger them polymorphically.

In C++, a simple command could look like this:

```
class Command
{
    int state_;

public:
    explicit Command(int state) : state_(state) {}

    void operator()() {
        // do something with your state
    }
};
```

Then you can store the list of commands:

```
std::vector<Command> commands;

commands.push_back(Command(1));
commands.push_back(Command(2));
// ...
```

And later on run them:

```
for (auto & c : commands)
    c();
```

Typically, you will want to have different kinds of commands, so `Command` would be an abstract class and then you would derive several different classes that represent different actions.

Then, in order to "nest" functions as you say (i.e. in order to compose commands), you can simply store `Command`s inside other `Command`s.

Of course, this is the OOP approach to the problem -- you can always flatten this and write an equivalent algorithm that reads some data structure which contains all the required parameters and perform the appropriate action at each step depending on them; instead of spreading it across different classes.

Finally, an extra note: in C++ there are many things that *can be called/invoked* ([`Callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable)): functions, function objects (like shown above), pointers to member functions, lambda expressions... If you want to go the OOP route and be completely general, you can easily take advantage of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (or similar implementations like [`boost::function`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/function.html) for pre-C++11), which is a general-purpose polymorphic wrapper that can store any of those.